# Function for addition

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a website as a small store for personal use, my main question here is how would I code a function for the additon of all of it?

six single check boxes for various types of peripheral devices including printer, monitors, modems or other devices with which you are familiar.  Assume the basic computer system price of $500.00 and then add appropriate prices based on user checks.
Monitor 299.99
Printer 129.99
Speakers 49.99
CDRW  159.99
Scanner  129.99
Modem  49.99

If I add just a scanner, my total will be $629.99.
If I add a modem and a monitor, my total will be $849.98.

Here is my current progress, I have not added too much JS code yet as I'm unsure of how I would add this function:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Problem 9</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Program name: Problem 9
// Purpose: Program 9 
// Author: Opack
// Date last modified: 2-13-12 
$(function() {
  function calculateCost() {
    var ret = 500;
    var $selected = $('input:checked', $peripherals);

    $selected.each(function() {
      ret += parseFloat($(this).attr('alt'));
    });

    return ret.toFixed(2);
  }

  function setCost() {
    $total.text(calculateCost());
  }

  var $peripherals = $('#peripherals');
  var $total = $('#total');
  $('input[type="checkbox"]', $peripherals).on('change', setCost);

  setCost();

});

</script>
<style>
  h1 {
    font-size: large;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="yellow">
    <h1>What peripherals do you want to add?</h1>
    <form id="peripherals">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Monitor" value="Monitor" alt="299.99">Monitor<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Printer" value="Printer" alt="129.99">Printer<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Speakers" value="Speakers" alt="49.99">Speakers<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="CDRW" value="CDRW" alt="159.99">CDRW<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Scanner" value="Scanner" alt="129.99">Scanner<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Modem" value="Modem" alt="49.99">Modem<br>
        <label for="Cost">Total</label><input type="text" name="Cost" />
    </form>
</body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my [attempt](http://jsbin.com/ipiyem/7/edit). I ended up using jQuery and updating the cost automatically. I attached the cost information to "alt" attribute of the checkboxes. It's possible to do this in some other ways as well. Tweak that to suit your purposes.

jQuery code in case jsbin goes bust...

```
$(function() {
  function calculateCost() {
    var ret = 500;
    var $selected = $('input:checked', $peripherals);

    $selected.each(function() {
      ret += parseFloat($(this).attr('alt'));
    });

    return ret.toFixed(2);
  }

  function setCost() {
    $total.attr('value', calculateCost());
  }

  var $peripherals = $('#peripherals');
  var $total = $('input[name="Cost"]');
  $('input[type="checkbox"]', $peripherals).on('change', setCost);

  setCost();
});
```

And relevant HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Cost Demo/title>
<style>
  h1 {
    font-size: large;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>What peripherals do you want to add?</h1>
    <form id="peripherals">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Monitor" value="Monitor" alt="299.99">Monitor<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Printer" value="Printer" alt="129.99">Printer<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Speakers" value="Speakers" alt="49.99">Speakers<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="CDRW" value="CDRW" alt="159.99">CDRW<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Scanner" value="Scanner" alt="129.99">Scanner<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Modem" value="Modem" alt="49.99">Modem<br>
        <label for="Cost">Total</label><input type="text" name="Cost" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It was missing the base cost. The math should be ok now.

Comment: Fixed it and tweaked it up a little, when I click a checkbox, it doesn't seem to add to the total cost though. :S

Comment: Could you share your code somewhere? I might be missing some logic here. Total cost is just based + cost of selected. That calculation is triggered each time a checkbox is changed.

Comment: My solution depends on jQuery. You'll need to link to it like this at the beginning: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> .

Comment: Still not getting an output, updated OP. Anyway you could edit your post with the full code of it all incase I'm missing something? I've never really tried query.

Comment: There you go. It's definitely possible to do this without jQuery or some other library. Just a tad harder.

Comment: Only thing I would want to do is add the total cost to output in a text box. Like so:
http://screencast.com/t/9H9B1Y1nllM

Answer (score 1):

Is this homework?

```
function calculation(a,b)
{
     return a + b;
}
```

SOURCE

[W3Schools: Javascript Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp) 
[W3Schools: Javascript Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp)

Comment: No, as explained in the OP it's for personal use.